# Explanation for anti-automorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, automorphism-group

https://books.google.si/books?id=NZHkBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=complementary+bases+for+dual+space&source=bl&ots=fWIjy8AHzt&sig=t9hUYoov-mcPEsSMWGn71YLrABg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjK9uCa9KjbAhVLPFAKHfkJANIQ6AEwAXoECAEQMQ#v=onepage&q=complementary%20bases%20for%20dual%20space&f=false

In this book on page 148, there is anti-automorphism defined, and then it says we can turn left vector space into right vector space using and anti-automorphism.

My question is:

$\alpha \rightarrow \alpha^A$ that is defined there as an inverse of an automorphism. For what there stands the power of A and could someone please explain this notation better?

Comment: It is just a notation. One can find it more or less intuitive, but I don't think that it is related to other situations in maths where one would use a power notation (such as, well, powers, or conjugation in groups).

Comment: I mean my question was how to we turn this left vector space into the right vector space using and anti-automorphism? I could not find any information online